# UITableViewCell: Dynamic Cell Height by 'Cell Identifier'

Tags: ios, uitableview

(note: The tableView I am using is from the Parse.com iOS SDK - PFQueryTableViewController)

**Scenario** = I have a TableViewController that has two different types of cells (each with their own identifier). Each object upon being queried and loaded into the datasource is checked if a key on the object is true. Depending on the result I dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to the correct cell.

```
-(PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    myTableViewCell *cell;

    if ([object[@"orientation"] isEqualToString:@"left"] || [object[@"orientation"] isEqualToString:@"right"]) {

        myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    else {

        myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
    }
```

This all does its job. Each cell is being loaded at the correct indexPath.row and everything. Problem is my tableView "Row Height" itself does not readjust for the new cell. This causes overlapping of cells and makes everything ugly. I can tell the tableView in storyboard to set the row height to whatever the larger of the two cell heights is, but that leaves big spaces in-between cells too which also makes it look ugly.

**Question** = It is my belief (and correct me if I'm wrong) that I need to use the

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method in order to achieve this. Where I need help is I am not sure how to set the height of each cell at indexPath depending upon the 'identifier' that I gave each cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

**What I'm looking for** = Something like this (please excuse the SuedoCode)

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([cell.identifier isEqual:@"Cell"] {

    return 100;

    }

    else {

    return 200;

    }
}
```

**ANSWER: I figured it out!** (I marked the answer below as accepted because it pointed me in the right direction)

Because I am using a PFQueryTableViewController all I had to do this...

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([object[@"orientation"] isEqual:@"left"] || [object[@"orientation"] isEqual:@"right"]) {

        return 100;
    }

    else {

       return 200;
    }

}
```

Comment: you're on the right track. Instead of self.tableView.rowHeight, you need to "return SomeHeight;". This method is called for each row, so you're returning a height for said row at said index path.

Comment: Thank you! I am confused though. What I typed above in my **What I'm looking for** section isn't runnable code. Because you can not check cell.identifier this way. My question here is _how_ then do I accomplish this? Please excuse the not returning anything part or my question. This was not a copy and paste. I wrote it in the question. The problem I am experiencing was not because of the lack of that code in my project.

Comment: @TomTesticool, what you can do is you can store the `cellIdentifier` in your model, and you can recall it in `–tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method from your original model (as you would recall any other information for building up the cell in the `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some things to keep in mind. heightForRowAtindexPath is calledbefore CellForRowatIndexPath, and simply says, if object is at indexPath X, then return Y or Z.

The more correct approach might be to subclass the tableCell class, set a property in the .h file and then figure out the path... I'll give you a dirty way :)

Create an NSMutableArray property (don't forget to init it somewhere/somehow), and based on your dataSource, populate it with Height A or Height B (a float). Now, back in heightForRowAtIndexPath, you can say something to the effect of:

```
return (int)self.myMutableArray[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I like your dirty suggestion :). It seems like it _Should_ work. But I when I try it I get, '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'.

Comment: You forgot to do self.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];  (when in doubt, just stick that line in viewDidLoad :)

Comment: What I did was, .h - @property NSMutableArray *mutableArray; // viewDidLoad - mutableArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // cellForRowAtIndexPath - [mutableArray addObject:@"floatString"]; // heightForRowAtIndexPath - return [[mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue]

Comment: I did mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array]; and it still, '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'. :(

Comment: Two possibilities. Some typo and the array was not init (so it's null), or some typo and you're not populating the array (so it's empty). You're darn close. Just set the breakpoints in debugger and walk through the code. Third possibility... I might be remembering incorrectly, but you probably don't need to alloc a property Array. Just do self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: I figured out why it is not loading in the heightForRowAtIndexPath. HeightForRowAtIndexPath is being called before cellForRowAtIndexPath. How do I get it to be called after cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Totally My bad. I double checked and you're right, heightForRowAtIndexPath is called first. So, instead we need self.mymutableArray to be populated earlier based on your PFObject datasource. Same principle, namely, we need to whether or not to set the size based upon the object in the datasource array used to populate your table. We just need to it earlier now, and so set the values for each indexpath.row based on that.

Comment: Hey Tim thanks for hanging in there with me on this. I think we are making some progress! To clarify, you said "We Just need to it earlier now, and so set the values for each indexPath.row based on that.". Do you mean 'earlier' as in do it in the viewDidLoad? And by 'based on that' do you mean like in my code where I'm checking the PFObject's '[@"orientation"]'? I'm cornfused.

Comment: I figured it out! I'm posting my findings above in my answer. Thank you for your help Timothy! You pointed me in the right direction with your answer so I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I know I already figured this out but I have now another application that I use the same technique. Not quite like there other so I can't use "my" own solution (that I put in my answer) for this application. So I had a question to ask you about your solution. It seems to make a lot of sense. Only thing is when I try to do `return self.rowHeightArray[indexPath.row];` I get an error: "`returning 'id' from a function with an incompatible result type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float')`". Do you know why this is happening? Does it happen to you?

Comment: This is a recasting issue, as the return call expects an int. So you can always do: int numericalValue = (int)testArray[indexPath.row];
return numericalValue ;